# Set Custom Document ID in flutter Cloud Firestore

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to set a custom document ID to new entries in my cloud Firestore but i cant seem to figure out how to do it, here is my code, it still generates a random ID

```
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("payment_links").add(
  {'id':  user_id.toString(),
  'link':
paymentlink.toString(), 'link_id': linker.toString(),
'amount':
c1.text.toString(),
'title':
c2.text.toString(),
'trxnid':
secureRandom.nextString(
      length: 15, charset: '0123456789').toString(),
      'payments' : 0



  }).then((value){
 
                                      
                                         
    print("================================sucess=============================================================");
    print(value.documentID);
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for posting a question to StackOverflow :) The way your code is formatted (mainly with regards to indentations) makes it hard to read which may make it harder for users to give quality answers and makes it harder on future users who may read your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want an automatic random ID, then don't use `add()`.  You should build a [DocumentReference](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentReference-class.html) to the document you want to create, and use [set()](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentReference/set.html) instead.

```
DocumentReference ref = FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection("payment_links")
    .doc("your-document-id");
ref.set({ ... });
```

I suggest reading the [documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#adding-documents) carefully where it says:

> If you'd like to specify your own ID, call the set method on a DocumentReference instead